# I wrote a code to swap two numbers but only one of the numbers gets swapped

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, swap

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(int *a , int *b){
    int temp;
    *a = temp;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf("enter the first number : ");
    scanf("%d" , &x);
    printf("enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%d" , &y);

    printf("the value of x and y before swap are %d and %d and the address of x and y are %u and %u\n" , x , y , &x , &y);
    swap(&x , &y);
    printf("the value of x and y after swap are %d and %d and the address of x and y are %u and %u\n" , x , y , &x , &y);
    return 0;
}
```

I WAS TRYING TO SWAP THE NUMBERS , WHILE THE VALUE OF X GETS SWAPPED WITH THE VALUE Y BUT THE VALUE OF Y DOSENT GETS SWAPPED WITH X AND IT SHOWS -2 IN THE OUTPUT.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT!

Comment: Wrong way round (and the compiler should have warned). `*a = temp;` should be `temp = *a;` Please don't ignore or disable compiler warnings.

Comment: `int temp; *a = temp;` The variable `temp` is uninitialized so you just overwrote what `a` points to with an indeterminate value.

Comment: oh i get it now , thnx for pointing it out

Comment: *Temp* is almost never a good name. Call it *oldA* instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap(int *a , int *b){
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
   
}
```

`temp` must be `*a` not `*a` must be `temp`